Is there a browser plugin that splits browser pages vertically ？
As shown in the picture, when I need to compare different rows at the same time, I can do so by pulling down the Vertical Split button in the top right corner of the IDE. Since I often read very long documents in my browser, I would like to ask if there is a plugin with similar functionality?


If there's really no such thing, can someone teach me how to implement this feature myself? Thanks!

I'd love to use a similar extension that in principle can be implemented as a Greasemonkey script or a web extension. The easiest (only?) solution I can think of is reloading the page doubling its loading using two <iframe> elements. This might have multiple negative effects on user experience. Also I'm not sure about the following aspects: Should the changes you make except navigation in one pane be reflected at the other pane? Woud like like to open distinct pages in other pane? If so, how would browser apply user actions from the toolbar above the page?

If I understand/remember correctly, discountinued Firefox extension mechanisms like XUL that might change the Firefox UI, might have other features other than using <iframe>s in the current tab page, but at least XUL was removed from the Firefox codebase recently. The closest thing I think of similar capabilities is sidebar stuff from the Web Extension APIs, but it doesn't look exactly like what you're looking for,

It seems that the most direct way to achieve this effect is to open the same web page and put the two windows side by side by using the window split function provided by windows 11.
